# symfony 3: trying to transform the value of field using DataTransform

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I have added this model transformer following the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html):

```
        ->add('subtotal', MoneyType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
        ))
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            // transform <br/> to \n so the textarea reads easier
            function ($originalDescription) {
                return $originalDescription;
            },
            function ($submittedDescription) {
                var_dump($submittedDescription); //<<<<<<<<<<<<
                // remove most HTML tags (but not br,p)
                $cleaned = strip_tags($submittedDescription, '<br><br/><p>');

                // transform any \n to real <br/>
                return str_replace("\n", '<br/>', $cleaned);
            }
        ))
```

The problem: the var_dump() you can see is outputting the whole entity as you can see below. I expected just the content of `subtotal` submitted field.

```
object(DefaultBundle\Entity\Bill)[682]
  protected 'id' => null
  private 'client' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\DefaultBundle\Entity\Client)[788]
      public '__initializer__' => null
      public '__cloner__' => null
      public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
      protected 'id' => int 1
      private 'bills' (DefaultBundle\Entity\Client) => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[436]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(Proxies\__CG__\DefaultBundle\Entity\Client)[788]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[151]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'client' (length=6)
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[465]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean false
          protected 'collection' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[801]
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean false
      protected 'name' => string 'Jose Manuel Fernandez Fernandez' (length=31)
      protected 'nif' => string '03113434P' (length=9)
      protected 'address' => string 'Bulevar' (length=39)
      protected 'phone' => string '633553423' (length=9)
      protected 'email' => string 'me@gmail.com' (length=21)
  protected 'numberPlate' => string 'fasdfdasf' (length=9)
  protected 'createdAt' => 
    object(DateTime)[453]
      public 'date' => string '2016-02-28 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Madrid' (length=13)
  protected 'serialNumber' => string '5' (length=1)
  private 'servicesPerformed' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'description' => string 'fasdf' (length=5)
          'quantity' => string '4234' (length=4)
          'unitPrice' => float 4234
          'price' => float 17926756
  protected 'subtotal' => null
  protected 'taxRate' => float 0.21
  protected 'tax' => float 3764618.76
  protected 'total' => float 21691374.76
```

Here you have the entity and the form type:

```
class BillType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $em = $options['em'];

        $builder
            ->add('serialNumber', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nº serie',
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
            ))
            ->add('createdAt', DateType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Fecha',
                'data' => new \DateTime("today"),
            ))
            ->add('client', null, array('label' => 'Cliente'))
            ->add('numberPlate', null, array(
                'label' => 'Número matrícula',
        //'data' => 'prueba'
        ))
            ->add('servicesPerformed', CollectionType::class, array(
                 'label' => false,
                 'entry_type' => ServicePerformedType::class,
                 'allow_add' => true,
                 'allow_delete' => true, 
                 'attr' => array('data-prototype' => 'jander'),
            ))
            ->add('subtotal', MoneyType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                //'grouping' => true
            ))
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                // transform <br/> to \n so the textarea reads easier
                function ($originalDescription) {
                    return $originalDescription;
                },
                function ($submittedDescription) {
var_dump($submittedDescription);
die("jlfs");
                    // remove most HTML tags (but not br,p)
                    $cleaned = strip_tags($submittedDescription, '<br><br/><p>');

                    // transform any \n to real <br/>
                    return str_replace("\n", '<br/>', $cleaned);
                }
            ))
            ->add('tax', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'I.V.A.',
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                'grouping' => true
            ))
            ->add('total', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Total',
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                'grouping' => true
        ))
            ->add('Guardar', SubmitType::class)
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) use ($em) {
                    $repository = $em->getRepository('DefaultBundle:Bill');
                    $result = count($repository->findAll()) + 1; 

            $form = $event->getForm();  
            $data = $event->getData();  

                    if (!$data) {
                      $form->add('serialNumber', TextType::Class, array(
                          'data' => $result, 
                          'label' => 'Nº serie',
                          'attr' => array('readonly' => true)
                      )); 
                    } else { 
                      $form->add('serialNumber', TextType::Class, array(
                          'label' => 'Nº serie',
                          'attr' => array('readonly' => true)
                      )); 
                    }
            }
            )
        ;
    }




    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DefaultBundle\Entity\Bill',
            'em' => ''
        ));
    }
}



/**
 * DefaultBundle\Entity\Bill
 *
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Bill
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id; 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="bills")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     **/
    private $client;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $numberPlate;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="date")
    */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $serialNumber;

    /**
     * Features of the product.
     * Associative array, the key is the name/type of the feature, and the value the data.
     * Example:<pre>array(
     *     'size' => '13cm x 15cm x 6cm',
     *     'bluetooth' => '4.1'
     * )</pre>.
     *
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $servicesPerformed = array();

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float")
    */
    protected $subtotal;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float")
    */
    protected $taxRate = TaxRate::TAX_RATE;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float")
    */
    protected $tax;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="float")
    */
    protected $total;

    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->numberPlate;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set numberPlate
     *
     * @param string $numberPlate
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setNumberPlate($numberPlate)
    {
        $this->numberPlate = $numberPlate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numberPlate
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNumberPlate()
    {
        return $this->numberPlate;
    }

    /**
     * Set servicesPerformed
     *
     * @param array $servicesPerformed
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setServicesPerformed($servicesPerformed)
    {
        $this->servicesPerformed = $servicesPerformed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get servicesPerformed
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getServicesPerformed()
    {
        return $this->servicesPerformed;
    }

    /**
     * Set subtotal
     *
     * @param string $subtotal
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setSubtotal($subtotal)
    {
        $this->subtotal = $subtotal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subtotal
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSubtotal()
    {
        return $this->subtotal;
    }

    /**
     * Set taxRate
     *
     * @param string $taxRate
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setTaxRate($taxRate)
    {
        $this->taxRate = $taxRate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get taxRate
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTaxRate()
    {
        return $this->taxRate;
    }

    /**
     * Set tax
     *
     * @param string $tax
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setTax($tax)
    {
        $this->tax = $tax;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tax
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTax()
    {
        return $this->tax;
    }

    /**
     * Set total
     *
     * @param string $total
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setTotal($total)
    {
        $this->total = $total;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param \DefaultBundle\Entity\Client $client
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setClient(\DefaultBundle\Entity\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return \DefaultBundle\Entity\Client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set serialNumber
     *
     * @param string $serialNumber
     *
     * @return Bill
     */
    public function setSerialNumber($serialNumber)
    {
        $this->serialNumber = $serialNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get serialNumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSerialNumber()
    {
        return $this->serialNumber;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: after the answer of @ejuhjav this is my `buildForm()` function:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $em = $options['em'];

        $builder
            ->add('serialNumber', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nº serie',
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                'data' => 6
            ))
            ->add('createdAt', DateType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Fecha',
                'data' => new \DateTime("today"),
            ))
            ->add('client', null, array('label' => 'Cliente'))
            ->add('numberPlate', null, array(
                'label' => 'Número matrícula',
        //'data' => 'prueba'
        ))
            ->add('servicesPerformed', CollectionType::class, array(
                 'label' => false,
                 'entry_type' => ServicePerformedType::class,
                 'allow_add' => true,
                 'allow_delete' => true, 
                 'attr' => array('data-prototype' => 'jander'),
            ))
            ->add('subtotal', MoneyType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                'data' => 6
            ))
            ->add('tax', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'I.V.A.',
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                'grouping' => true,
                'data' => 6
            ))
            ->add('total', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Total',
                'attr' => array('readonly' => true),
                'grouping' => true,
                'data' => 6
        ))
            ->add('Guardar', SubmitType::class)
        ;

        $builder->get('subtotal')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                // transform <br/> to \n so the textarea reads easier
                function ($originalDescription) {
                    return $originalDescription;
                },
                function ($submittedDescription) {
                    //var_dump($submittedDescription);
                    die("IT IS _NOT_ ENTERING HERE!!! :)");
                    // remove most HTML tags (but not br,p)
                    $cleaned = strip_tags($submittedDescription, '<br><br/><p>');

                    // transform any \n to real <br/>
                    return str_replace("\n", '<br/>', $cleaned);
                }
            ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting your model transformer to the whole form. To add the transformer into single field use either (from the referenced docs):

```
$builder->add('description', TextareaType::class);

$builder->get('description')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
...
```

or

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->addModelTransformer(...)
);
```

Comment: I have pasted the a new `builderForm()` function in my qustion following you answer. but after submitting the form the function that handles the transformation of `subtotal` is not being called. Look at my code.

Comment: the new version of the model transformer addition works fine for me (in 2.3): just tried adding it to some random form of mine and the functions did get invoked...

Comment: yes, I did see that - that's why I mentioned which version I tested it on. I somehow doubt that there would be some difference in the working in this case related to the symfony version as your code (and the same one that I tried) is copied from the symfony3 documentation (but unfortunately I don't have that much free time to verify that assumption)... but nevertheless, too bad that I couldn't help to solve your problem. Maybe you could still try to attach that model transformer to some another trivial form just in case there happens to be something fishy with this form/entity.